# Проблемы с заголовком диалогового окна

Tags: c++, winapi

столкнулся с такой проблемой как изменение заголовка диалогового окна, в зависимости от получения результата с хостинга.

Есть такой код:

```
string GetUserDayCount()
{
    std::string Serial = GetSerial64();

    std::string UrlRequest = PATH;
    UrlRequest.append("gate.php?day=" + Serial);

    static std::string ReciveDay = GetUrlData(UrlRequest);
    if (ReciveDay == "0")
    {
        return "Example | Осталось менее дня";
    }
    else {
        return "Example | Осталось дней: " + ReciveDay;
    }
```

Вызывается он следующим образом:

```
GetUserDayCount().c_str()
```

Если с таким созданием окна у меня не было проблем:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "Example", GetUserDayCount().c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 300, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
```

то как впихнуть это в диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю я что-то по типу лоадера, который показывает в заголовке сколько дней осталось подписки, получая информацию с сайта.

с WinAPI начал знакомиться только недавно, раньше делал все только на ImGui, желательно описать все подробно, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну так а каким образом вы создаете свое диалоговое окно?

Answer (score 1):

Функция из WinApi

```
BOOL SetWindowText(    
  HWND hWnd,        // дескриптор окна или элемента управления
  LPCTSTR lpString  // адрес строчки    
);
```

Дальше всё зависит от ЯП.

Answer (score 1):

Заголовок любого окна, диалогового в том числе, меняется функцией `SetWindowText`. Вот только у вас окно не вполне диалоговое. Диалог создается не функцией `CreateWindow`/`CreateWindowEx`, а одной из функций `CreateDialog`, `CreateDialogParam`, `CreateDialogIndirect`, или `CreateDialogIndirectParam`. Они тоже базируются на `CreateWindow`, так что отличия небольшие, но они все же есть.

Еще надо добавить, что `CreateDialog*` создают немодальный диалог, а для модального нужно использовать `DialogBox*`, где отличий гораздо больше.